# How to get Jacoco reports for the Karate test feature files using gradle

Tags: gradle, jacoco, karate

How to get Jacoco reports for the Karate test feature files using Gradle.

My project is a Gradle project and I am trying to integrate jacoco report feature in my project for the karate tests. The server is running in my local on 8080 port.

I am doing the following way to generate jacoco report and please let me know is my approach correct and also give me a solution to get the jacoco report for the gradle project.

1) First I am trying to generate jacoco execution data with the help of jacocoagent.jar as follows with a Gradle task:

```
java -javaagent:/pathtojacocojar/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/pathtojocofile/jacoco.exec -jar my-app.jar
```

2) Next, I am running a Gradle task to generate the report

```
project.task ('jacocoAPIReport',type: org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport) {
    additionalSourceDirs = files(project.sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)
    sourceDirectories = files(project.sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)
    classDirectories = files(project.sourceSets.main.output)
    executionData = fileTree(dir: project.projectDir, includes: ["**/*.exec", "**/*.ec"])
    reports {
        html.enabled = true
        xml.enabled = true
        csv.enabled = false
    }
    onlyIf = {
        true
    }
    doFirst {
        executionData = files(executionData.findAll {
            it.exists()
        })
    }
}

          project.task('apiTest', type: Test) {
                    description = 'Runs the api tests'
                    group = 'verification'
                    testClassesDirs = project.sourceSets.apiTest.output.classesDirs
                    classpath = 
                   project.sourceSets.apiTest.runtimeClasspath
                    useJUnitPlatform()
                    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
                    finalizedBy jacocoAPIReport

                }
```

I don't see any of my application's classes in the jococo.exec file. I think, bcz of that I am always getting the coverage report as 0%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The server is running in my local on 8080 port.

I don't think that is going to work. Depending on how your code is structured you need to instrument the code of the server.

I suggest trying to get a simple unit test of a Java method to work with Gradle. If that works, then use the same approach for the server-side code and it will work.

Comment: In the same project, For the unit tests, the jacoco report is getting generated with code coverage, the unit tests work bcz they run on same JVM and the class file would be available,  but for the karate tests, the report is with 0% coverage. I am trying to use javaagent.jar for instrumenting the code of the server

Comment: @HimaBindu that's right - ideally the server has to be *started* in the same JVM and this is the existing Karate example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo#code-coverage-using-jacoco - sorry I can't help with any other approach, I've heard it is possible but difficult - here is one link that may help https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jacoco/NWG1pW5Bpi8

Comment: @HimaBindu , did you get solution for your issue??