# Jacoco 0% coverage on karate test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, karate, jacoco

[image]

#### I am unable to figure out why coverage is 0 even though the tests run successfully

I clone the Spring Boot Example https://github.com/Sdaas/hello-karate
and updated the pom.xml to include Jacoco

```xml
    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>karate/KarateTests.java</include>
                        <include>karate/person/PersonRunner.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <!-- pass jacoco runtime agent to JVM so we record code coverage when tests run -->
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ${argLine}</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

You can check my change in my minimual reproduced project here https://github.com/yatw/JacocoKarate/commit/bbe1fc9eb89d8c166f4fb1ab51e9f4250992cc67

Similiar questions like [Is it possible to get code coverage with karate tests for java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69297222/5777189)
and [How to get Jacoco reports for the Karate test feature files using gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59124741/5777189) both point me to this example https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/pom.xml#L160
Which I don't know what I am missing

Thank you

Comment: sorry I have no idea. you seem to be on the right track and reading the right docs. getting this to work can indeed be hard, it requires some research and digging around

Comment: same for me, did you solve it?
@BabyishTank